# What's the algorithm behind sort() in Swift

Tags: algorithm, swift, sorting

I read recently the documentation section of Apple about [Algorithms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Algorithms.html) mainly focused in the Sorting algorithms.

But I can't find any article in which it explains what's the algorithm behind the `sort(_:)` and `sort(_:_:)` functions in Swift. (e.g Quicksort, MergeSort, Heapsort, etc).

Comment: What a completely misnamed page. It doesn't talk about algorithms at all. "Utilities" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Side note: I searched on "What algorithm does Swift's sort function use?" on A Famous Web Search Engine and the top hit was an SO question. I reviewed the question and its answers, confirmed this is a duplicate of that question, and came back here to vote to close-as-duplicate...only to find the Martin R had already done so, referring to the very question I'd found. Always worth a search before posting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I search it first but I don't see it the google results. My mistake